# Close Bootstrap Dropdown on Container/Body click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have added some animation to Bootstrap's drop-down but now the only way to close it is to click the button. Not being very experienced I was hoping for some help, what I want is to close it when one clicks on Container/Body.

```js
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 50px 0 0 250px;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out 0s, -moz-transform 0.2s ease-out 0s, visibility 0s ease-out 0.1s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out 0s, -o-transform 0.2s ease-out 0s, visibility 0s ease-out 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-out, visibility 0s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.1s;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out 0s, transform 0.2s ease-out 0s, visibility 0s ease-out 0.1s;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu.collapsed {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
  visibility: hidden !important;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu.expanded {
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transform: translateY(12px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(12px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(12px);
  transform: translateY(12px);
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">
    Dropdown
  </button>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu collapsed" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
    </li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(document).on('click', function() { $('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('expanded') })`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This does seem to do the trick but it also allows me to open it on container click. I only want it to open through the button.

Comment: Switch `toggleClass()` to `removeClass()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve this by adding a click function to the **body** or **document** and then check the target **class** or **id** and based on that you choose what to do, here's a snippet for your case

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    var clicked = $(e.target);
    var opened = $(".dropdown-menu").hasClass("expanded");
    if (opened === true && !clicked.hasClass("dropdown-toggle")) {
        $(".dropdown-toggle").click();
    }
});
```

here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/9duqrovc/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following to add your custom CSS class:

```
$('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
  // e.relatedTarget is the toggling anchor element
  e.relatedTarget.next().toggleClass('expanded');
})
```