# Bootstrap 5: How to properly toggle dropdown with another button

Tags: dropdown, bootstrap-5

So I have a dropdown menu and next to it a button. The aim is for the button to open and close the dropdown menu, and clicking on the text in the dropdown box should also open and close the menu.

I've been trying to adapt the working Bootstrap 3 code from this post [Toggle bootstrap button dropdown using another button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42476070/toggle-bootstrap-button-dropdown-using-another-button/42477393) for Bootstrap 5 but can't get it fully working as I would like it to. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

My code is below:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a id="test-dropdown-btn" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Select Category</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item">All Categories</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item">Categoty One</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item">Categoty Two</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item">Categoty Three</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item">Categoty Four</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item">Categoty Five</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

 <a id="test-btn" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-target=".btn-group">&#9660</a>
```

jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Ernesto1/gefvd0s1/17/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Bootstrap 5 you can no longer toggle the Dropdown from another element using the data attributes. However, it can be done using JavaScript...

```
let trigger = document.getElementById('test-dropdown-btn')
document.getElementById('test-btn').addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
    bootstrap.Dropdown.getOrCreateInstance(trigger).toggle()
})
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/NtUf3WpgRb)

---

Note: The `auto-close` option must be set to false for this to work.

Comment: For anyone else that comes along, to close the dropdown when an item is selected add the toggle to a click event on the item, for example `$(document).on("click", ".dropdown-item", function(event) {
    bootstrap.Dropdown.getOrCreateInstance(trigger).toggle();
});` And `bootstrap.Dropdown.getOrCreateInstance(trigger).hide();` is useful to close the menu on a different click event where you just want to close and not toggle the dropdown.

Comment: Update: Using Zim's answer and the answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35390019/14944162. The menu now closes when page is clicked or item selected. Code in next comment. Hope it helps someone else here.

Comment: `let trigger = document.getElementById('categoryDropdown');

            $(document).click(function (e) {
                let clicked = $(e.target);
                let opened = $("#categoryDropdownMenu").hasClass("show");
                if (e.target.id === 'secondDropdownBtn') {
                    bootstrap.Dropdown.getOrCreateInstance(trigger).toggle();
                }
                else if (opened === true && !clicked.hasClass("dropdown-toggle")) {
                    bootstrap.Dropdown.getOrCreateInstance(trigger).hide();
                }
            });`

Comment: @Zim I'm using Bootstrap's Custom Selects instead of dropdowns - can the same method be used to trigger these via Javascript? I was hoping it's as simple as replacing 'bootstrap.Dropdown' with something else, but I can't find any documentation on what element to specifically call.